# UHC Ruler getting started

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I have just read about [UHC's Ruler](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ruler) and would like to use it in my own project.
However, trying to compile examples from [paper](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/bin/view/Ehc/RulerProgrammingTypeRules) about it gives me a bunch of syntax error messages.
Is there any examples of rule files (which can be compiled with version from hackage - 0.4.0.0) to start with?

Comment: @AndrewC this question is not compiler-specific

Comment: @AndrewC I'm successfully compile this package (using GHC) - it is tool that uses it's own "rules file" syntax and compile it to haskell code (similar to how yacc/bison/happy works). And I have problems trying to figure out how to write this "rule files".

Answer (score 0):

There are example ruler files in the `demo` and `test` folders of the [github repository.](https://github.com/UU-ComputerScience/ruler)

The full text of the `tst4` file looks like a good minimal case:

```
scheme Y =
  hole [ a: A, b: B  | | ]
  judgeshape tex a `=` b

rules y scheme Y "" =
  rule y =
    judge Y = a `=` b
    -
    judge Y = b `=` a
```